# Kendo Autocomplete Overriding Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I am currently using Kendo UI as well as Bootstrap in a project and I am coming across a problem where Kendo Autocomplete is overriding the bootstrap css class `form-control`. Is there anyway to stop the autocomplete from overriding the Bootstrap style?

As you can see it is overflowing the normal input that Bootstrap applies:
[image: Kendo look]

This is the autocomplete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#txtName").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: data,
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Select product..."
    });
</script>
```

And this is the form where I am using the `form-control`:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtName">Product name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="txtName" type="text" placeholder="Name of the product"/>
    </div>
```